# NPM keeps deleting my 'build' folder while installing

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a sub-folder called 'build' in my project folder. Anytime I run `npm install -g`, it deletes my sub-folder 'build' which is very important to the running to the  app

Comment: Sounds like you have a `preinstall` or `postinstall` script configured in `package.json` that removes that folder, because I've never known `npm` to remove it by itself.

Comment: Oh! cool. I will check that out